# Terraform dynamic inside dynamic

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

The idea is to generate something like this:

```
  environment {
    ...

    environment_variable {
      ...
    }

    environment_variable {
      ...
    }
  }
```

Where there is a environment block with some properties and 0...n environment_variables with some properties.

I am having the following module which uses a dynamic inside a dynamic. Is this possible? Or how would I achieve this?

What i have so far is the following module which uses a dynamic inside a dynamic:

module:

```
dynamic "environment" {
  for_each = var.environment_definition

  content {
    field1 = environment.value.field1
    field2 = environment.value.field2

    dynamic "environment_variable" {
      for_each = length(var.environment_variables) == 0 ? [] : [var.environment_variables]

      content {
        name  = environment_variable.value.env_name
        value = environment_variable.value.env_value
      }
    }
  }
}
```

variables.tf:

```
variable "environment_definition" {
  description = ""
  type = any
  default = {}
}

variable "environment_variables" {
  description = ""
  type = map(object({
    env_name  = string
    env_value = string
  }))
  default = {}
}
```

And the above module with its variables is called in my main.tf:

```
  environment_definition = {
    field1                = "value"
    field2                = "value"
  }

  environment_variables = {
    tf_version = {
      env_name  = "TERRAFORM_VERSION"
      env_value = "0.12.28"
    },
    aws_account = {
      env_name  = "AWS_ACCOUNT"
      env_value = "Account123456"
    },
    environment = {
      env_name  = "ENVIRONMENT"
      env_value = "dev"
    }
  }
```

However I am getting this error:

```
Error: Missing map element

  on ../../../modules/codebuild/main.tf line 123, in resource "aws_codebuild_project" "this":
 152:           value = environment_variable.value.env_value
    |----------------
    | environment_variable.value is map of object with 3 elements

This map does not have an element with the key "env_value".
```

How can I successfully implement this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the problem is that u call the root variable so instead of the `each.value`:

```
content {
        name  = environment_variable.value.env_name
        value = environment_variable.value.env_value
      }
```

the problem is that you put you map inside an array with this:

```
  for_each = length(var.environment_variables) == 0 ? [] : 
   [var.environment_variables]
```

so you are now handling an arry of a map that means for the first element

> key = 0  and
> value = tf_version = {
> env_name  = "TERRAFORM_VERSION"
> env_value = "0.12.28"
> }

your code should be :

```
dynamic "environment_variable" {
      #solution1
      for_each = var.environment_variable
      #solution 2 am not sure this works but so you get the prob
     for_each = length(var.environment_variables) == 0 ? {} : 
   var.environment_variables
      content {
        name  = environment_variable.value.env_name
        value = environment_variable.value.env_value
      }
    }
```

and also you should try to change dynamic name it's better

```
content {
        name  = <dynamic_name>.value.env_name
        value = <dynamic_name>.value.env_value
      }
```

https://www.hashicorp.com/blog/hashicorp-terraform-0-12-preview-for-and-for-each/

Comment: Ok it seems I need some more practice with basic Terraform... I think TF is rather unhandy to code with

Comment: What do you mean by this:     name  = <dynamic_name>.value.env_name

Comment: hello , i meant you should use different variable name so you don't get confused

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this? Since you have a map, I think you should use `key` and `value` instead.

```
dynamic "environment" {
  for_each = var.environment_definition

  content {
    field1 = environment.value.field1
    field2 = environment.value.field2

    dynamic "environment_variable" {
      for_each = length(var.environment_variables) == 0 ? [] : [var.environment_variables]

      content {
        name  = environment_variable.key
        value = environment_variable.value
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The example below was extracted from the Terraform's blog and think it described what you're trying to do:

```
# Configuration for Terraform 0.12

locals {
  standard_tags = {
    Component   = "user-service"
    Environment = "production"
  }
}

resource "aws_autoscaling_group" "example" {
  # ...

  tag {
    key                 = "Name"
    value               = "example-asg-name"
    propagate_at_launch = false
  }

  dynamic "tag" {
    for_each = local.standard_tags

    content {
      key                 = tag.key
      value               = tag.value
      propagate_at_launch = true
    }
  }
}
```

Reference: https://www.hashicorp.com/blog/hashicorp-terraform-0-12-preview-for-and-for-each/

Comment: hello Rafael , if you look you can see that he is already using key and value